# What does Harry Dean Stanton mean by "Old pond; Frog jumps in; Splash!"

Tags: american-cinema, david-lynch

The great [Harry Dean Stanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Dean_Stanton), in this [gem of an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvlm0XCBtsk) with the legendary [David Lynch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Lynch), says this at the very end:

> Old pond; Frog jumps in; Splash!

What are they referring to?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is a question about a quip in an interview, unrelated to the topic of movies & TV.

Comment: IMO, there's still *a lot* about Movies & TV here: it's an interview with an actor and a filmmaker, and about knowing/understanding more about them. It's not totally unrelated (shrug)

Comment: @OldPadawanBut so is every other celebrity gossip about someone who happens to appear in films. It's not clear from the question how the quote is relevant for their work and their films in any way.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The question is about an interview between two celebrated film personalities about their lives and film careers. How would I know before asking the question if the quote is relevant to their films or not? If/when you have 5 minutes, please consider watching the interview, this is definitely not a gossip question at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Equally important, that interview itself is an extract from a feature length documentary, which can be considered TV.

Comment: I watched it and that little haiku really has no bearing on anything, I'm afraid, at least in that interview excerpt. ;-) I mean, sure, OldPadawan gives a reasonable explanation as to what it generally means. But afterall, it's juist some dudes conversing about life in general, be they legends of filmmaking as much as they want.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I understand and partially agree with you. Thank you for your kind reply and taking the time to watch it 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 古池や　蛙飛び込む　水の音
>
> The old pond
>
> A frog leaps in.
>
> Sound of the water.

This probably refers to one of the masterpieces of the Japanese culture, a [haiku poem by Matsuo Basho](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.masterpiece-of-japanese-culture.com/literatures-and-poems/frog-old-pond-haiku-matsuo-basho%3famp) known as [The Old Pond](https://poemanalysis.com/matsuo-basho/the-old-pond/).

Its message is considered meaning:

> The beauty of life is found in simple moments.

It's often associated to "*carpe diem*", because it's about enjoying the little things of life and seeing them as simple and beautiful.

> Carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero ([Carpe Diem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem))